# Travelling to Europe when 1 month before expiry of BRP

Tags: schengen-visas, visa-expiration, uk-residents, visa-renewals

I intend to travel Spain for a wedding in mid-June and my BRP visa expires in mid-July. I am currently holding a UK Spouse visa and have to apply for extension in July. Can I still apply for a Schengen visa or are there chances to get the visa if I apply now?